# Can I use a facade in Blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I've installed the package https://github.com/ElForastero/Transliterate. 
I've done all steps from the guide.

My `aliases`  is

```
'aliases' => [

    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
    'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
    'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
    'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
    'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
    'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
    'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
    'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
    'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
    'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
    'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
    'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
    'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
    'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
    'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
    'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
    'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
    'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
    'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
    'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
    'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
    'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
    'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
    'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
    'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
    'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
    'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Transliterate' => ElForastero\Transliterate\Facade::class,

],
```

My `providers` is

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */
    ElForastero\Transliterate\ServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

],
```

I would like to write something like this in my Blade template:

```
     @foreach($services as $service)
            <div class="content" data-content="{{ Transliterate::slugify($service->tag) }}">
                <div class="list-previews-cases -closed">
                    <div class="cases">
                        @foreach($service->cases as $case)
                        <div class="case">
                            <img
                                src="{{ $case->preview_img }}"
                                class="img"
                                alt="">
                            <div class="title">{{ $case->title }}</div>
                            <div class="description">{{ $case->description }}</div>
                            <a href="/" class="link -blue">#{{ $service->tag }}</a>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    @if($service->cases->count() > 1)
                    <span class="spoiler">More...</span>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

But as the result I see the following:

[image]

What is wrong? Can I use Facade in my Blade template?

Comment: Yes you can use Facade in blade, is it working in controller ? `Transliterate::slugify($service->tag)`

Comment: if you use `ElForastero\Transliterate\Facade::slugify($service->tag)` instead of `Transliterate::slugify($service->tag)` does it work?

Comment: Thank you. It works from the box.

Comment: Do not forgot to use the root namespace (represented by the first ```\``` in the namespace) ```\Transliterate::slugify($service->tag)``` or ```\ElForastero\Transliterate\Facade::slugify($service->tag)```.

Comment: Did you remember to clear any cached configuration files with `php artisan cache:clear`, and `composer dump` just to be sure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to MVC, you shouldn't use any complex logic in your view files. Consider moving it to your controller like this:

```
use ElForastero\Transliterate\Facade as Transliterate;

...
$slug = Transliterate::slugify($service->tag);
return view('your.view', ['slug' => $slug, ...]);
```

If you still want to access your facade in the view file, you can do this by specifing full path to it's class like so `ElForastero\Transliterate\Facade::slugify(service->tag)`

You can also wrap it into a helper function, if you expect to call this code multiple times in many places. Just create a new function in your `Helpers/functions.php` like so:

```
use ElForastero\Transliterate\Facade as Transliterate;

...
function slugify($tag) {
    return Transliterate::slugify($tag);
}
```

And then call it in your view like so: `{{ slugify($service->tag) }}`